# How does rails determine the path from an object?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been working on implementing my own ORM. And I was wondering how the rails path helper extracts the ID from the object. For example how would I make this work for my ORM?

```
@contact = Contact.first
contact_path(@contact)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:**

My object does have an ID attribute and responds to it. But yet the path helper returns an error.

Comment: This has more to do with rails routing than ORM.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell you want to be activemodel compliant. This will make url helpers, form_for(@contact) and so on work.

You also get to (optionally) use a bunch of modules  dealing with 
things such as validations, dirty attributes etc.

There are only a handful of methods you have to implement. There's also an 
[ActiveModel::Lint](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Lint/Tests.html) module that tests that your implementations of these 
primitives are valid, and which also serves as documentation. In particular you need to implement `to_param` and `persisted?`. I think some of the naming stuff only gets used if you do stuff like `link_to 'foo', @contact`

Answer (score 0):

The method checks to see if you've passed it an object, or an integer. If it's an object and that object has an `id` method (`respond_to?(:id)`), it uses its ID. Pretty dead simple.

Comment: I thought it was that simple. My object does respond to ID, but I still get an error when trying to use the path helper.